# How to pass route params in Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm using the context API and I have this in my context file:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getSingleCountryData() {
      const result = await axios(
        `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${props.match.alpha3Code.toLowerCase()}`
      );
      console.log(result)
      setCountry(result.data);
    }
    if (props.match) getSingleCountryData();
  }, [props.match]);
```

In the component I'm using, it doesn't work because it doesn't know what the props.match.alpha3Code is. How can I can pass the value? The alpha3Code is coming from the URL: `localhost:3000/country/asa` where `asa` is the alpha3Code, how can I get this value?

Basically, what I'm trying to do is. I have a list of countries I listed out on the home page. Now I'm trying to get more information about a single country. The route is `/country/:alpha3Code` where `alpha3Code` is gotten from the API.

FWIW, here is my full context file:

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const CountryContext = createContext();

export default function CountryContextProvider(props) {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountryData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(
        'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all'
      );
      setCountries(result.data);
    };
    getCountryData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getSingleCountryData() {
      const result = await axios(
        `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${props.match.alpha3Code.toLowerCase()}`
      );
      console.log(result)
      setCountry(result.data);
    }
    if (props.match) getSingleCountryData();
  }, [props.match]);

  return (
    <CountryContext.Provider value={{ countries, country }}>
      {props.children}
    </CountryContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

In the component I'm using the `country`, I have:
`const { country } = useContext(CountryContext);`

I know I can do this from the component itself, but I'm learning how to use the context API, so I'm handling all API calls in my context.

The API I'm making use of is [here](http://restcountries.eu/)

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/peoray/where-in-the-world)

Project Github [link](https://github.com/peoray/where-in-the-world)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the context from a component using it by passing down a setter function which updates the context state.

```
export default function CountryContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState([]);
  const [path, setPath] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getSingleCountryData() {
      const result = await axios(`your/request/for/${path}`);
      setCountry(result.data);
    }
    if(path) getSingleCountryData();
  }, [path]);

  return (
    <CountryContext.Provider value={{ countries, country, setPath }}>
      {children}
    </CountryContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Now use `setPath` to update the request endpoint with the route match once this component is mounted.

```
const Details = ({ match }) => {
  const {
    params: { alpha3Code }
  } = match;
  const { country, setPath } = useContext(CountryContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPath(alpha3Code);
  }, [alpha3Code]);

  return (
   <main>Some JSX here</main>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Details);
```

Linked is a working [codesandbox implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-kilby-9njuz)

Answer (score 3):

> In the component I'm using, it doesn't work because it doesn't know
> what the props.match.alpha3Code is. How can I can pass the value? The
> alpha3Code is coming from the URL: localhost:3000/country/asa where
> asa is the alpha3Code, **how can I get this value**?

I guess the root of your problem is this one. You have no idea which the `aplha3Code` parameter comes from. I have dived into your GitHub repo to make it clearer.

1. First,  `match` is one of react-router provided terms. When you use something like `props.match, props.history, props.location`, you must have your component wrapped by the `withRouter`, which is a Higher Order Component provided by `react-router`. Check it out at [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter). For example, below is the `withRouter` usage which is provided by react-router:

```
// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```

`ShowTheLocation` is wrapped by the `withRouter` HOC, which will pass all the route props (match, history, location...) to `ShowTheLocation` through props. Then inside `ShowTheLocation`, you are able to use something like `props.match`. Clear enough?

So back to your problem! You have not wrapped any components by `withRouter` yet, have you? Stick to it and have some fun! You will figure it out soon!

Also, please be aware that you **must place your component under the `BrowserRouter` to be able to use the react-router things**

2. If you want to go with Hooks, please take a look at this super useful one:

   https://usehooks.com/useRouter/

It wraps all the `useParams, useLocation, useHistory, and use useRouteMatch` hooks up into a single `useRouter` that exposes just the data and methods we need. Then, for example, inside your component, do it like this:

```
import { useRouter } from "./myCustomHooks";

const ShowMeTheCode = () => { 
   const router = useRouter();
   return <div>This is my alpha3Code: {router.math.params.alpha3Code}</div>;
}
```

---

**Update 1 from Peoray's reply:**

This is where the problem occurs:
https://github.com/peoray/where-in-the-world/blob/cb09871fefb2f58f5cf0a4f1db3db2cc5227dfbe/src/pages/Details.js#L6

You should avoid calling `useContext()` straightly like that. Have a look at my example below:

```
// CountryContext.js
import { useContext, createContext } from "react";

const CountryContext = createContext();

export const useCountryContext = () => useContext(CountryContext);
```

Instead, you should wrap it by a custom hook like `useCountryContext` above. And then, inside your `Details` component, import it and do like:

```
import React, from 'react';
import { useCountryContext } from '../contexts/CountryContext';

const Details = (props) => {
  const { country } = useCountryContext();
  ...
}
```

---

**Update 2 from Peoray's reply:**

Although I have stated it in advance for you, I just feel like you did not make enough effort to go through what I said.

Also, please be aware that you **must place *your component* under the
`BrowserRouter` to be able to use the react-router things**

In your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/peoray/where-in-the-world), it shows the `Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` error. Okay, as I said above, you have not moved the `ContextCountryProvider` to under the `BrowserRouter` to get the `useRouter` work.

I have fixed it for you, and the screen popped out, please check it at [updated codesanbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/move-countrycontextprovider-to-under-browerserrouter-jc82h). You will get what you need at **App.js** file.

Although it still throws some Axios bugs there, I think my job is done. The rest is up to you.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. Got `TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined`. Not sure, if I'm doing it right. I updated the repo if you wanna take a look :)

Comment: First of all, I think you're still fresh to React & react-router. Therefore, you should remove the Context API, and play around with react-router things such as `withRouter` HOC first. Once you get used to the React world, this is when the Context API, Hooks come to rescue. Upvote and mark accept if you find my advice useful!

Comment: Hey there, I did take a look in your updates. I think I got it here. Wait for my update!

Comment: @Peoray Hey there, I have updated my answer. Please have a look at `Update 1 from Peoray's reply` for details. I think everything is okay now.  Dont forget to upvote and mark accept if you find it useful!

Comment: Did you try this and it worked? Because the previous method was working very fine for the `Home.js` file.

Also, I'm not new to React :), just new to the updates, my day job is Vue, so I'm trying to get back to speed with React :)

Comment: Here is a codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/peoray/where-in-the-world

Comment: I have updated my answer again. Hope this is the last time, the rest is up to you. Please check `Update 2 from Peoray's reply` for details. Please be grateful by upvoting or marking accept! Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a great answer. I've removed a bit of a telling-off - while that may well have been correct in this case, it is not relevant for the many other readers who will learn from this answer in the future. We also discourage asking for votes here - while there is a hope that grateful question authors will accept/upvote, we would rather not see voting/meta-commentary in posts (it's OK in comments if you think the OP does not know about the acceptance system, but go easy on it).

Answer (score 0):

You might use `useParams` hook to get everything you need inside your context provider. [Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks)

Something like this:

1. import `useParams` in file where your Provider component is
2. in your `CountryContextProvider` add this at the top of the component:

```
const { alpha3Code } = useParams();
```

3. update `useEffect` which needs `props.match`

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getSingleCountryData() {
      const result = await axios(
        `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${alpha3Code.toLowerCase()}`
      );
      console.log(result)
      setCountry(result.data);
    }
    if (alpha3Code) getSingleCountryData(); // or if you need `match` - do not destructure useParams()
  }, [alpha3Code]);
```

Comment: If I import useParams in the file where your Provider component is, which in my case: `src/pages/Details.js`, I'm getting a defined but not used, how do I use it?

In my repo, I'm using the `props.match` but nothing is happening, still returns empty

Comment: It said on step 2: "in your CountryContextProvider add this at ..."

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that :(

Comment: It means it should be inside this curly brackets: `export default function CountryContextProvider(props) {...}` before or right after `useState` lines

Comment: I got an: `TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined`

Comment: Have you passed context to it?

Comment: What do you mean, pass context to it?

Comment: useContext(CountryContext)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure but I do have  `const { country } = useContext(CountryContext);` in my `Details.js` where I'm suppose the results from the API. I don't know if that's what you mean

Comment: Actually, you should have `const { countries, country } =  useContext(CountryContext);` - but you could ommit constants that you don't need

Comment: I have no need for the countries which returns all countries. I'm already using that and it's working. Check my code, that's the first `useEffect` I'm doing and I'm using the countries in my `/src/pages/Home.js` file

Comment: In regards your error, check is component which uses context - inside context provider

Comment: I have the path this way: `path='/country/:alpha3Code'`